# Microsoft auth doesn't redirect after successful login

Tags: django, azure-active-directory

I am integrating Microsoft's login using [Django Microsoft Authentication Backend](https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I have managed to to get a successful response and create a new "Microsoft" user and am able to see it in the admin site if I login to the admin site as a local superuser.

[image]

[image]

When I login using Microsoft, the pop up window to Microsoft opens, authenticates, and it doesn't redirect to anywhere.
[image]

But, with a local non-Microsoft user, it can successfully redirects to the admin panel.

[image]

I don't understand why this is so, it doesn't make sense. I have a frontpage constructed that I would like this login page to redirect to after successful login. I have included

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

in the settings.py file but that does not change anything.

Comment: On your logs what errors throws your app? I believe your MS app for oauth doesn’t know what to do with the request, what urls do you set on azure to callback your project??

Comment: The app does not throw any errors. I get a 201 request code and it just stays there, does not redirect to another page. The redirect URI is set as `http://localhost/microsoft/auth-callback/` . I've had errors thrown when the callback URI was wrong, that's resolved now. The user authentication returns a 201, but it doesn't seem like Django creates a user session and redirects the user to the home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real weird when trying to use Microsoft authentication with localhost. I installed ngrok, added the ngrok https URL as callback URL in Azure AD, added ngrok URL to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in settings.py then tried logging in through admin page, it logs in to admin panel fine now.

To use redirects, I added a "Sign in with Microsoft" image in the default login.html page that django's default authentication provides. That then redirects to "/microsoft/to-auth-redirect/". To make use of this, the callback URL in Azure AD must be "/microsoft/from-auth-redirect/". Now you can make use of `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` and `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` in settings.py.

Comment: Thank you! the login redirect can be give to the login decorator.